# Seperate External and Internal Traffic using Google tag Manager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to seperate different type of traffic for my website based on domain name.

For seperating based on domain name I am trying to use react google tag manager. I added  react gtm code in app.js as follows:-

```
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'

const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-000000'
}
 
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
...
 
const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} />, app)
```

This works and I am able to see page view event in tag assistant.

[image]

The part where I need help is that I don't understand how to differentiate between 2 page view events - one arising from external and other from internal users.I am planning sepearte them based on domain names . If any one has any idea reagarding this can you please guide me?

Comment: if you want a good answer, you really want to improve this question. You're asking too many questions in one without really properly describing your situation and user journeys.

Comment: Edited question for better understanding

Comment: when you say domain, do you actually mean hostname of current site, or the domain of the referrer?

Comment: by domain i mean like gmail.com for external users and mycompnay.com for internal users.

Comment: oh well then you differentiate by the referrer dimension. Or by the Source.

Comment: I dont know what is referrer dimension neither I know how to differentiate past TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs). Could you please guide me on this and thank you.

Comment: you don't need to do anything in the tag manager. Referrer should be tracked with default pageview tags. So if you have them firing, just go to GA and look into its dimensions.